# How do I get to the Casino?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

I am about to get Celsius. Is that too early in the game?

I keep talking to the Inn keeper and she does not give me the option to stay up during the night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. After you get past the scene where

> Regal talks to Alicia in Altamira

if you go to the Inn you get a scene and the Theater and Casino are open and available by speaking to the woman at the counter and then choosing that you want to stay up.